# How to make snippet format a variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Is it possible to make a snippet to produce code that looks like below while only using one tab stop? Or at least having `SomeVar` as the placeholder by the time the user tabs to it.

```js
const someVar = SomeVarClass();
```

My current attempt fails to recognize the `pascalcase`

```json
{
  "Initialize variable to it's class": {
    "prefix": "ivtc",
    "body": [
      "const ${1:someVar} = ${1:/pascalcase}Class()",
    ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When tabbing the transformation will take place, the solution looks like

```json
{
  "Initialize variable to it's class": {
    "prefix": "ivtc",
    "body": [
      "const ${1:someVar} = ${1/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}Class();",
    ],
  }
}
```

I can then use the previous transformation as a variable by wrapping it

```json
{
  "Initialize variable to it's class": {
    "prefix": "ivtc",
    "body": [
      "const ${1:someVar} = ${2:${1/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}}Class();",
      "$2",
    ],
  }
}
```